# Angular2 download ZIP using POST with GET override

Tags: angular, download, zip, jax-rs, corrupt

I'm sending data in JSON format to a server from an Angular2 client and expecting a ZIP file in return.

I have written a JAX-RS method to generate a ZIP file and put it into the /tmp directory for downloading.  I have no problems getting the JSON downloadInfo from the client or generating the ZIP file, so I've skipped these in this example.  All this example does is send a response which is a pre-created ZIP file.

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@POST
@Path("test-download")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public Response getZip(String downloadInfo,
                       @Context SecurityContext securityContext)
{
  System.out.println("downloadInfo=" + downloadInfo);
  File zipFile = new File("/tmp/file.zip");
  return Response.ok(zipFile)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFile.getName())
      .build();
}
```

I am using a POST with GET override because I need to send a large amount of data in the request and some of the request data contains characters which cannot be URL encoded.  The request data is not shown here.  Here is the pertinent Angular2 code:

```
downloadZip(): void {
    let downloadZipUrl = 'http://myserver/test-download';
    let json: any = {};
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('responseType', ResponseContentType.Blob);
    headers.append('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'GET');

    this.http.post(downloadZipUrl, json, {headers: headers}).subscribe(response => {
      var blob = new Blob([response['_body']], {type: 'application/zip'});
      var url= URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
    });
}
```

When I run this, I do download a ZIP file, but the ZIP file appears corrupted.  If I 'cat' the downloaded file to the screen, I see a bunch of Unicode replacement characters (question mark inside diamond).  If I 'cat' the original ZIP, I do not see these characters.  Also, the size of the downloaded file is larger than the original file.

I have done quite a bit of research on this and have tried various incarnations of media types (application/octet-stream, application/zip) in both the Angular2 client and JAX-RS server, and charset's in the client, all to no avail.

**Update 10/4/2018**

If I hit the URL with a browser (without the Angular2 client) the ZIP downloads correctly.  This points to a problem with the Angular2 side.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I got this working.  Here is my solution.  The back-end JAX-RS method:

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@POST
@Path("test-download")
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response getZip(String downloadInfo,
                       @Context SecurityContext securityContext)
{
  System.out.println("downloadInfo=" + downloadInfo);
  File zipFile = new File("/tmp/file.zip");
  return Response.ok(zipFile)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFile.getName())
      .build();
}
```

What changed in the JAX-RS method from the question to the solution?  Nothing really.  I did change "application/octet-stream" to "application/zip", but I tested both and both work.

The Angular2 code:

```
downloadZip(): void {
    let downloadZipUrl = 'http://myserver/test-download';
    let json: any = {};

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'GET');

    let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});
    options.headers = headers;

    this.http.post(downloadZipUrl, json, options).subscribe(response => {
        // Get the file name from the content disposition.
        let contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
        let fileName = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
        fileName = fileName.replace(/"/g, '');   // Get rid of double quotes.

        // Get and automatically download the file.
        let blob = new Blob([response._body], {type: 'application/zip'});
        let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.setAttribute('href', url);
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
        downloadLink.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    });
}
```

What made the difference?  Using the RequestOptions:

```
let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});
```

At one point I did try putting:

```
{responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob}
```

in the http.post call itself, but it didn't work for me.  Maybe I did it wrong.